# How do I compile an ASP.NET website into a single DLL file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dll, compilation, web-deployment-project

I have finally finished my web site. I published it, and I was surprised at the results. Although the App_Code compiled into a single DLL file, every page's code behind compiled into its own DLL file. How do I make it so that it is one DLL file?

Also, is it possible to compile everything (SubSonic, AJAX, etc.) into that same single DLL file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might prefer to use the web application project style for that.

You can use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en) to merge assemblies into one.

Comment: I agree - a web app is the way to go. Convert your project to a web app.

Answer (score 4):

To accomplish this you will have to covert your project into a Web Application Project (Supported in Visual Studio 2005 SP1 and Visual Studio 2008).

The process of converting is not that hard, but you will need to move everything out of the app_code folder, as WAP (Web Application Projects) projects do not have code inside app_code.

Once you do this, everything inside your project is compiled into a single DLL file, any external assemblies are still contained in their own DLL files though, but there are options around that as well.

Answer (score 4):

The way we do it is by adding a deployment project to our site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336619.aspx

Answer (score 3):

We use build scripts for our websites and run the aspnet_merge.exe from the command line. Here's the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx